What is this rectangular SMD part with a stripe along one of the long edges?

The dimensions are 1.60mm x 3.20mm.
Schematically, the side without the white stripe is connected to this node in a buck/boost converter...

Here is the part in context, with the transistors Q1-Q4 labeled in sharpie...

I am unable to trace where the other side is connected except for the shown decoupling caps that go to ground.
While it seems like it could be that resistor shown to the left in the schematic, the right side does not seem to be connected to ACP. There also seems to be a 3rd contact on the bottom right corner of the package...


My guess is a 4-terminal sense resistor. Maybe one of the sense terminals is not visible because it's soldered under the package.

Could you show a wider view, perhaps there are designators around, other context clues?

Is this from a TI reference design for the BQ25703A, or from something else? Is a bill of materials available?

@TimWilliams Context photo added. thx.

@JohnD This is a great guess and consistent with the function I'd expect at this location.  I'll probe out that extra pin and see if it connected to the larger adjacent pin, and also try to find a match component. Thx!

@ChesterGillon Yes, this is a "psudeo-schematic" from the datasheet. It only shows the general topology of a suitable application, rather than an actualizable design. The DUT does not exactly follow it.

@JohnD There was in fact an extra pin hiding under under the bottom left corner, and this is indeed the exact 4-pin resistor part chesterGillon posted in his answer below based on your suggestion. Thank you!

Based upon the comment from @John D, and the dimensions, it could be a  Littelfuse L4CA0612 Four-Terminal Surface Mount Resistor
The datasheet has the following picture:


The dimensions are:

Width: 3.20±0.20
Length: 1.55±0.20


Interesting part! What purpose would a part like this be used for? I see the datasheet says it has separate voltage sensing terminals, though I'm curious why separate terminals are needed for that

@JordanMelo The datasheet mentions Kelvin sensing, also known as Four-terminal sensing. As it says on that linked Wikipedia page It is common to provide 4-wire connections to current-sensing shunt resistors of low resistance operating at high current
